# Is there a way to scrape variable information from the source files or folder names that my artifact is built from?

Tags: tfs, automation, continuous-integration, azure-devops, build-automation

I have automated a build/deploy process in Azure Devops / TFS and would like to scrape a file or folder name as a variable from the source file path that is used for my build artifact.

For example, I might want to scrape the folder name of the folder at the build source path and store it for use in the build #, release #, etc.

I have gone through Microsoft's documentation and I believe the information I'm looking for might be associated with the following... but I can't seem to find the right location.

```
Release.Artifacts.{alias}.BuildURI  #The URL for the build.

Azure pipelines example: vstfs://build-release/Build/130
GitHub example: https://github.com/fabrikam/asp
```

When I attempt to locate the folder name from the source, I have so far been unable to find it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's not possible to get the source file &            folder name/Artifact name from the environment variable.

As of now, you need to specify the `Artifact alias name` in order to access the artifact related information.

E.g, `Release.Artifacts.{alias}.DefinitionName`

[General Artifact variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#artifact-variables)

[Primary Artifact Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#primary-artifact-variables)

Using default variables, you can use the default variables in two ways - as parameters to tasks in a release pipeline or in your scripts.  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#using-default-variables)